# How do I move horses without golden apples or carrots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I have a nice world, I have a diamond sword, and a full set of iron armour. I'm level 32, and I have an abundance of crops. But there is one thing I cannot figure out: What is the damn way to get animals? I know I can lead them into a pen with their favorite food, but I live in a PLains biome, and I know horses eat golden carrots and apples, but I don't have any gold and my mine does not show any sign of getting me any. How do I get a horse into a pen without its favorite food?

Answer (score 1):

Horses can be bred with golden apples, and healed with golden carrots, normal carrots, wheat, and haybales, but they don't follow the player holding these anyway.

Instead,

Option 1: Obtain or craft a lead. Kill a wandering trader or just block his llamas so they can't follow him so the leads are broken and drop as items, or craft a lead using string and slimeball.
[image]

Option 2: Obtain a saddle - find it in a treasure chest or fish it out (requires fishing in ["open water"](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing#Junk_and_treasure),) or if you dare, trigger an illager raid and kill a Ravager, then [tame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse#Taming) the horse, equip it with the saddle and ride it wherever you desire.

Comment: Yes, a lead is definitely the way to lead a horse. Also, when you are leading a horse with a lead, you can then right click a fence post, while holding the lead to tether the horse to the fence post with the lead.

Answer (score 0):

Horses can only be lead via their favorite food in bedrock edition. You are playing on java, so sadly there is no way to lead horses without the lead item.